# how to print elements of multiple arrays with numpy.logical_and?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm fairly new to python and I had a question about `np.logical_` functions, in particular `np.logical_and()`. How can I display the elements for which the boolean is true for two separate arrays? Take the below code as an example:

```
# create arrays:
import numpy as np
my_house = np.array([18.0, 20.0, 10.75, 9.50])
your_house = np.array([14.0, 24.0, 14.25, 9.0])

# (1) find which areas of my_house are greater than 18.5 or smaller than 10:

print(np.logical_or(my_house>18.5, my_house<10))
# this results in: [False  True False  True]

print(my_house[np.logical_or(my_house>18.5,my_house<10)])
# this results in: [20.   9.5], giving the elements for which the boolean is true. 

# (2) find the areas of both my_house and your_house which are smaller than 11:

print(np.logical_and(my_house<11,your_house<11))
# this results in [False False False  True]
```

how can I write a code that returns the elements for both arrays for which the boolean is true in question 2? In the first question, I could do it with `my_house[np.logical_()]`.  But how can I do that when I am calling on both `my_house` and `your_house`? Or is it not possible?

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: Not entirely clear what you want. Do you want to concatenate the elements of the arrays, or find locations where both match the criteria? What actual final result are you looking for?

Comment: I'm not sure how python would format it, but I want the output to be the elements of both my_house and your_house that are less than 11 (in the same index location). For my_house, that would be [9.50] and for your_house, that would be [9.0].

Comment: You can do on similar lines : `my_house[np.logical_and(my_house<11,your_house<11)` and `your_house[np.logical_and(my_house<11,your_house<11)]`. If you need to "merge" these together, use `np.concatenate` among others.

Comment: Also, use variables to hold your references between calls

Answer (score 1):

This how it is usually done in vectorized / `numpy` way:

```
>>> table = np.column_stack([my_house, your_house])
>>> table
array([[18.  , 14.  ],
       [20.  , 24.  ],
       [10.75, 14.25],
       [ 9.5 ,  9.  ]])
>>> idx = np.logical_and(my_house<11, your_house<11)
>>> idx
array([False, False, False,  True])
>>> table[idx]
array([[9.5, 9. ]])
```

The main advantage here is that you can access items of table using boolean or integer indexes at once plus it performs much faster than using list comprehensions.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a list comprehension that does what you are looking for:

```
x = [[my_house[i],your_house[i]] for i in range(len(my_house)) if 
    np.logical_and(my_house<11,your_house<11)[i] == True]
# output: [[9.5, 9.0]]
```

This assumes that my_house and your_house are the same length.
It iterates over both arrays, applying your np.logical criteria. On a value of True, it stores the values from my_house and your_house.

Here is the expanded code from the list comprehension that does the same thing:

```
for i in range(len(my_house)):
    if np.logical_and(my_house<11,your_house<11)[i] == True:
        print(my_house[i], your_house[i])
# output: 9.5, 9.0
```

Comment: Thank you! this is what I was looking for.  I appreciate it!

Comment: just try to avoid list comprehensions while operating with `numpy`

Comment: @mathfux what can go wrong with list comprehensions while using NumPy? I'm pretty new and just learning all this, so this is my first experience with comprehensions

Comment: Outputs are usually identical to ones that can be achieved by `numpy` action but, despite this, performance is slower. Becausy `numpy` is based on C.